# Why does Haskell give me this parse error on input '->'?

Tags: visual-studio, haskell, parse-error

I have looked through stackoverflow trying to figure this out, since I see alot of questions titled the same as mine. But I get this parse error in a Haskell file which worked perfectly the last time I opened it. I get this error-message
[image]

Comment: You forgot the double colon (`::`) to specify the type of `concat`.

Comment: Please replace your image with plain text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One defines a signature for a function by writing the name of the function, then two consecutive colons (`::`), and then the signature. You forgot the double colon, you thus write the signature of your `concat` function with:

```
--     ↓↓ double colon
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```